# Else statement to print once in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to print "no date" once?

I always print like this

```
no date
no date
24 - 8 - 1995
no date
no date
no date
no date
no date
03 - 12 - 2014
no date
....
```

i want print like this

```
24 - 08 - 1995
03 - 12 - 2014
no date
15 - 10 - 1995
no date
```

this is the code

```
import os

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('D:/Workspace'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.c'):
            for line in open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r").readlines():
                if line.find('date') != -1:
                    print line
                    break
                else:
                    print "no date"
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the [`else` after the `for` loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'date' in line:
            print line
            break
    else:
        print "no date"
```

This way, the `else` part will execute if the loop executed normally, i.e. if it was not exited via `break`.

Also you might want to use `with` so the files are closed properly, and iterate the file object directly instead of needlessly loading its entire content into memory with `readlines`, and use `in` instead of `find`.